# loop for table columns

Tags: php, loops

I have simple table with office list and 3 options for each.
What I need is a simple loop to add the same name to each cell in different office row. I;ve tried to loop it through php, but I'm quite new with it so so it numbered it by the numeric order, not making differences between rows:

```
<tr>
  <td name="1"></td>
  <td name="1"></td>
  <td name="1"></td>
  <td name="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td name="2"></td>
  <td name="2"></td>
  <td name="2"></td>
  <td name="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td name="3"></td>
  <td name="3"></td>
  <td name="3"></td>
  <td name="3"></td>
</tr>
and so on
```

Comment: Please add your complete source code.

Comment: Use loop inside loop 

 

For($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
Echo '<tr>';

For($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
Echo '<td></td>';
}
Echo '</tr>';

}

Comment: This my answer I can't put it from mobile

Comment: You want loop for above mentioned HTML?

Answer (score 0):

you php code sshould look like something like this ....

```html
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){ 
                     
     echo '<tr>'; 
                     
       for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){

          echo '<td name='.$i.'></td>'; 

        } 

     echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

but if you want to add string names you can put them in an array like this

```html
$array = new array(name1,name2,name3,name4);

  for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
                       
       echo '<tr>'; 
                       
        for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){ 

          echo '<td name='.$array[$i].' > </td>'; 


        } 

      echo '</tr>'; 
  }
```

the outpout should look like this

```html
<tr>
  <td name="name1"></td>
  <td name="name1"></td>
  <td name="name1"></td>
  <td name="name1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td name="name2"></td>
  <td name="name2"></td>
  <td name="name2"></td>
  <td name="name2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td name="name3"></td>
  <td name="name3"></td>
  <td name="name3"></td>
  <td name="name3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td name="name4"></td>
  <td name="name4"></td>
  <td name="name4"></td>
  <td name="name4"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
echo '<table>';  // Table start
for($i=1;$i<4;$i++){                      
   echo '<tr>';   // tr start                  
     for($j=0;$j<4;$j++){
        echo "<td name='$i'></td>";   // print td
      }           
   echo '</tr>';  // tr end
}
echo '</table>'; // Table end
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep all table data in array like this

```
$data_table = array(
    array(cell_11, cell_12, cell_13, cell_14),
    array(cell_21, cell_22, cell_23, cell_24),
    array(cell_31, cell_32, cell_33, cell_34),
    array(cell_41, cell_42, cell_43, cell_44),
);
```

And use two loops in your template:

```
foreach ($data_table as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $cell) {
            echo '<td>' . $cell . '</td>';
        }
    echo '</td>';
}
```

But be careful, you need to take care of the correct size of the array.